# I have a Russian Tortoise. Should I let him hibernate from fall till spring without feeding him? Or should I wake him up?

Tags: health, reptiles, tortoises

I have an estimated 15 year old Russian tortoise who I've had for 5 years. I typically leave his lights off throughout fall. This year he's gone through winter, too. Should I be doing this or is it healthier to keep his lights on year round and feed him every day?

Comment: I cannot give you a definite answer, but for the most common pet tortoises like Red Eared Slider it's adviced to let them hibernate in a cold and dark place like the fridge. Lights alone don't start or end hibernation, the temperature is crucial. If you keep your tortoise too warm without foot it will starve.

Comment: @Elmy RES turtle live in the water, while tortoises are living most times at land. Because of this I am carfull with conclusions from one to the other. In general the animal needs to have enough weight before starting the hibernation (look for weight-tables for the single species). And it should have visited a vet before to exclude health issues during hibernation.

Answer (score -1):

I would say dont wake him up. If you want to give him food, then stick it in the hole/next to his shell and he will eat when he wants to. However waking him up may scare him or make him mentally ill.

Comment: Because, If you wake him up suddently, he might go into shock. "To wake your tortoise up you should place your tortoise in a warm room for a few hours. And gradually it will start to wake up. After emerging from hibernation, your tortoise will be dehydrated, so it is very important to provide your tortoise with a shallow bath each day at this stage." According to https://www.exoticdirect.co.uk/news/how-care-tortoise-after-hibernation

Comment: Yes, thanks for that source, but that still doesn't explain a turtle suddenly becoming mentally ill.

Comment: Going into shock can be considered mentally ill in a way

Comment: Kind of. Not 100%, but I see your reasoning.

Comment: Thank you my good sir.